# Why am I not getting one item by id?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, routes

When I follow the route: '/gallery' I get all the items from the file './posts.json' and display them on screen. But when I turn the route: '/gallery/:id' I want to receive one item by its `id`. But I get all the elements of the array, as when going on the route '/gallery'.

**Tell me what I am doing wrong, and how to get the item by its `id` when I cross the route:'/gallery/:id'**

**app.js:**

```js
const express = require('express');
const Database = require('./db');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;
const db = new Database();

app.use(express.json());

app.get('/gallery', (req, res) => {
    if (req.query.id) {
        const picture = db.read(req.query.id);
        picture.then(data => {
            res.send(data);
        })
    } else {
        const pictures = db.read();
        pictures.then(data => {
            res.send(data);
        })
    }
});

app.get('/gallery/:id', (req, res) => {
    const picture = db.read(req.query.id);
    if (!picture) {
        res.status(404);
        res.send();
    } else {
        picture.then(data => {
            res.send(data);
        })
    }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
});
```

**db.js:**

```js
const fs = require('fs');
class Database {

    read (id) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            fs.readFile('./posts.json', 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err)
                }else if(id) {
                    const formatePicture = JSON.parse(data);
                    const pictureId = formatePicture.find(p => p.id == parseInt(id));
                    resolve(pictureId)
                }
                else {
                    resolve(data)
                }
            })
        })
    }
}

module.exports = Database;
```

**posts.json:**

```
{
  "posts": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "date": "2018-10-22T14:10:37.578Z",
      "title": "accusamus beatae ad facilis cum similique qui sunt",
      "url": "https://i.pinimg.com/originals/90/39/16/903916b9f0db6992f1a4b66ae3129fbe.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "date": "2018-10-22T14:10:37.578Z",
      "title": "reprehenderit est deserunt velit ipsam",
      "url": "https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/okup/images/d/da/C683c20a5b0ae062b2325653f2fd3bdf.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20170131193210&path-prefix=da"
    }
      ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `app.get('/gallery/:id')`, I think [`req.param`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.param)  is what you need instead of
`const picture = db.read(req.query.id);`

Comment: i changed const picture = db.read(req.query.id); to  const picture = db.read(req.params.id); 
and in the console node there was an error: "const pictureId = formatePicture.find(p => p.id == parseInt(id));" TypeError: formatePicture.find is not a function

Comment: First, `find` is an `Array` function.
So, in line  `const formatePicture = JSON.parse(data);`, your `data` is an object. You need to access its `posts` property which is an array.